# Javascript bind event handler of another function activating / ending

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, is there some way to bind and event handler of one function activating and ending?

So, for instance, I have two functions:

`function one() { console.log("this is function one") }`

and

`function two() { console.log("this is function two") }`

I want function two to activate both when function one is called and when it ends. Obviously, I could just:

`function one() { two(); console.log("this is function one"); two() }`

but that'd be boring -- not nearly as interesting as this way.

Comment: Here's [a worked example of getting aspects and pointcuts going in JS from scratch](https://smthngsmwhr.wordpress.com/2013/06/23/aspect-oriented-programming-in-javascript/) -- but this feels like an XY problem maybe? What exactly is it that you're trying to do?

Comment: *"but that'd be boring"* - Boring code is usually more reliable than "interesting" code.

Comment: @nnnnnn Well, if the answer ends up being super complicated, I probably won't use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you could write a function that wraps the original function in another that calls the callback.

```
function bindStartEnd(originalFn, callback, thisArg) {
    return function() {
        var returnValue;
        callback();
        returnValue = originalFn.apply(thisArg || null, arguments);
        callback();
        return returnValue;
    };
}
```

It could be used like this:

```
function one() {
    console.log("This is function one");
}
function two() {
    console.log("This is function two");
}
var three = bindStartEnd(one, two);
three();
```

And it could be extended to also accept two callbacks, one for the beginning and one for the end.  You might also think of a better name.

Comment: So, as I understand it, you pass in a: the double-executed function, and b: the origininal function, and then it returns a function which will execute the three?

Comment: @Quelklef The first parameter is the original function, `callback` is the double-executed function.

Comment: Right, my bad. [Not executing twice for me](http://codepen.io/Quelklef/pen/dYGwxX?editors=001), odd

Comment: @Quelklef That's because you have to pass it functions.  You're calling the console.log function immediately and then passing its return value.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it could be used?

Comment: @Quelklef Sure thing.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I was trying to define a function with `bindStartEnd`, not a variable. Thank you!